# Why no RDL files in TFS build output from SSRS project?

Tags: ssrs-2008, tfsbuild

My build manager is trying to automate deployment of the RDL and RDS files from my SSRS 2008 project to a folder on the build server.  The TFS build service says the build succeeded but there is nothing in the output folder.  There are two warnings shown (below) but I'm not sure if they're related to the lack of output.  When I build the project/solution from VS2008 a bin/Debug folder is created and it does contain the RDL/RDS files.

Warnings: (A) The specified solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.  (B) No files were selected for publishing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message: "The specified solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU" is invalid", is causing noting to be executed. Builds are based on a configurations (in vs richtclick your solution and click configurations), and the configuration of a solution must match the one you are using in your build. In this case the configuration Any CPU is missing and you need to create it.

After you have done that, you will probably get a new warning: Project type not supported by mesbuild. On the lowest level team build uses msbuild to "build" a given project. If you open a C# project you will therefore see that the file is a msbuild file, and contains all the information msbuild needs to compile it. The reason you are not seeing output is that SSRS projects are not msbuild files (and therefore can't be build with msbuild).

If you add a C# project, one can ad a post build step to copy the report files to the correct location.